# What does "git commit -vam " accomplish?

Tags: git

I would like to ask what does the command **"git commit -vam "message" "** accomplish, 
because I have seen no difference with the command **" git commit -m "message" "**
Thanks!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: notably `-a` -> `--all`, `-v` -> `--verbose`, `-m` -> `--message`

Answer (score 3):

`-a` -> `-all` Stage all files that have been modified or deleted

`-v` -> `--verbose` Show the diff between your changes and HEAD

`-m` --> `--message` Commit Message for your commit.

The Man page for Git lists all of the arguments the git command can take, with a detailed description of their purpose: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/

You can also access this from any *nix system via `man git`

Answer (score 3):

As many tools from the Linux ecosystem, Git command line supports two kinds of options:

- short options; they consist of a minus (`-`) followed by a single letter or digits; f.e. `-v`, `-a`, `-m` etc;
- long options; they start with two minuses (`--`) that are followed by a word (letters and digits); f.e. `--verbose`, `--add`, `--message` etc;

Both kinds of options can have values. The value of a short option follows the option after a space (e.g. `-m subject`). The value of a long option follows the option after an equal sign (e.g. `--message=subject`).

Two or more short options can be combined into a single word after the minus sign. E.g. `-vam` is the same as `-v -a -m`. At most one of them can have a value; the option that has a value should be the last one in the word and the value follows it as usual (separated by a space).

To summarize:

```
git commit -vam "message"
```

is the same as:

```
git commit -v -a -m "message"
```

which is the same as:

```
git commit --verbose --add --message "message"
```

Read more about [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and its options.

---

N.B. `git -commit` (as you wrote it in the question) is not a valid Git command or option.

```
$ git -commit
Unknown option: -commit
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

You can always get help about Git by running `git help` on your command prompt. To get help about a specific Git command (`commit`, f.e.) run `git help <command>` (replace `<command>` with the actual command name, f.e. `git help commit`).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [git-commit documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html), the "v" option causes the command to be verbose.
The important change with "-vam" is that the "a" option make

```
git add -u
```

before git commit.