# What does the -am do in: git commit -am "message"

Tags: git

I usually use `git commit -m "my message"` but reading the [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/pbountblog/deploy/heroku-git) guidelines to deploy an application I saw: `$ git commit -am "make it better"`.

What does the `a` part do?

Comment: Please note that you can answer your own questions like this in virtually every command line tool with something like `git commit -h`.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45151327/4265352) on a duplicate question. Also try reading the documentation of [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), also available on your command line as `git help commit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-a` flag *tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted*. Is the same as doing

```
git add -u
```

It is a convenient way of doing `add` and `commit` in one line, when you want to commit every change in your working copy.

You can find all the details in the documentation of [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and [add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) commands